# WPF ComboBox SelectedItem Disappears when Edit Dialog invoked

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

(Question modified for better clarity)

I've been researching all day and nothing really clears up my issue.   I have a combobox that gets its source from a collection of a "Bonus" that has a Name and a Code.

```
<ComboBox  Margin="4"
     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedBonus, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Bonuses, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
     DisplayMemberPath="Name"
     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

"Bonuses" is a collection that is retrieved from a file initially.   The combobox is properly filled with the collection, and I can select any of the items in the list.

Can't post image, so here is the link to the loaded list on startup: https://www.flickr.com/photos/mav_2007/14059399414/in/set-72157644402662271

Now, the following code is called on a context switch (right click the combo-box and select "edit Bonus").   However, here is where I cannot make any sense of what's going on with WPF and bindings.

In the code below, the method called "EditBonus" resets the combobox list be re-reading the file to make sure nothing has changed (`Bonuses.Clear()` is called, then rebuilt, and SelectedItem set).   But, as soon as I make the call to ShowDialog, the combobox selected item goes blank.  If I un-comment the OnPropertyChanged calls below, the problem appears fixed.  But, I do not understand why that works, and there is a case I can't fix where an exception in the Save operation of the dialog makes that combo box disappear again.

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Handle the "edit bonus" command
    /// </summary>
    void OnEditBonus()
    {
        // only edit this is we have a bonus selected
        if (bonusEditViewModel.EditBonus())
        {
            // OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBonus");
            var window = new BonusEditDialog(bonusEditViewModel);
            window.ShowDialog();
            // OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBonus");

        }
    }
```

And the method `EditBonus()`:

```
    internal bool EditBonus()
    {
        bool success = false;

        if (SelectedBonus != null)
        {
            var originalCode = SelectedBonus.Code;
            success = UpdateBonuses(originalCode);
            if (success)
            {
                if (SelectedBonus.Code == originalCode)
                {
                    BonusName = SelectedBonus.Type;
                    originalBonusName = BonusName;
                    CloseWindow = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Now, I've tried changing the `UpdateSourceTrigger` types and the modes and nothing makes a difference.

I believe it is related to the changing of the datacontext when accessing the dialog, and yet still making modification to the combobox's itemSource.   But I'm not sure how I can defer the combobox update until the dialog exits.

This is what it looks like if I try to edit the list without calling that `OnPropertyChanged` after returning from `EditBonus()` (note the empty combobox):
https://www.flickr.com/photos/mav_2007/14035815226/in/set-72157644402662271

And this is what it looks like if I make the call just after returning from `EditBonus()`:
And I would love to show you this, but I guess I'm not "reputable" enough :(  (You can see all images for this issue on my Flickr page from that link)

Thanks for any help you can give

Additional information (Possible culprit identified):

The DataContext for SelectedBonus is BehaviorViewModel, but there is another SelectedBonusProperty inside BonusEditViewModel.  Both BehaviorViewModel and BonusEditViewModel derive from ViewModelBase, which is where the OnPropertyChanged handler actually executes the handler based on ViewModel type.   BehaviorViewModel is what is bound to the form.   Calling OnPropertyChanged inside BonusEditViewModel has no effect because it is a different context.

Here is the SelectedBonus property inside BehaviorViewMode:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Expose the bonus information from the bonusEditViewModel
    /// </summary>
    public Bonus SelectedBonus
    {
        get
        {
            return bonusEditViewModel.SelectedBonus;
        }
        set
        {
            bonusEditViewModel.SelectedBonus = value;
            if (behavior != null && bonusEditViewModel.SelectedBonus != null)
            {
                behavior.Items[BehaviorItem.THEME_ID].Value = bonusEditViewModel.SelectedBonus.Code.ToString();
            }
            if (bonusEditViewModel.SelectedBonus != null)
            {
                ThemeShortname = bonusEditViewModel.SelectedBonus.Type;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBonus");

        }
    }
```

And here is the code for the SelectedBonus inside BonusEditViewModel:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// The currently selected bonus which will be edited by the dialog
    /// </summary>
    public Bonus SelectedBonus
    {
        get { return selectedBonus; }
        set
        {
            selectedBonus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBonus");
        }
    }
```

The function OnEditBonus() exists inside the BehaviorViewModel, and it calls the method UpdateBonuses() on the BonusEditViewModel object.   Now I'm wondering the best way to fix this...

Comment: What is the problem ? Is it that you are not able to set the SelectedBonus back selected on UI after clearing the list.

Comment: Sort of.   Inside EditBonus, after calling UpdateBonuses(), which clears and rebuilds the bonus list, I can clearly see that the bound properties Bonuses and SelectedBonus have valid values.  However, calling window.ShowDialog() clears the control on the UI unless I add that one extra OnPropertyChanged method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was verified to be with the structure of the code, which had a binding to the property SelectedBonus in the ViewModel class called BehaviorViewModel.   However, the property in this class actually gets its data from a property in the ViewModel class called BonusEditViewModel.   Calling "OnPropertyChanged("SelectedBonus") inside the BonusEditViewModel class has no effect on the property bound in BehaviorViewModel.   The code needs to be restructured so that the SelectedBonus property in BehaviorViewModel does not reference the property in another ViewModel.   This is just poorly structured code.